# Spring REST Implementation Error 404

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I am trying to develop a test REST application, by using the tutorial from [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). I am deploying it as a war, by including war in my pom, and have built the application with no errors. When it comes to opening the URL, `localhost:8080/gs-rest-service/rest/greeting` I am getting a 404 error - more specifically a `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/gs-rest-service/rest/greeting] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'`. I can't seem to see what is wrong, I have checked that my context root is set to `gs-rest-service`, and my GreetingController class looks like this:

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public @ResponseBody Greeting greeting(
        @RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                        String.format(template, name));
}
```

}

Here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And here is my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="home" />

<mvc:annotation-driven /> 
</beans>
```

[image: This is my project layout:]

Would anyone be able to help me identify the issue here?

Comment: Please post your startup logs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring RESTful Service as a WAR instead of JAR in Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820029/spring-restful-service-as-a-war-instead-of-jar-in-tomcat)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Where are the logs located?

Comment: The same place you found `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/gs-rest-service/rest/greeting] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'`.

Comment: Shouldn't the service method be annotated with a \@GET, \@POST, etc ? AFAIK, you have not associated a HTTP method with your service.

Comment: @AmitSharma That's what `@RequestMapping` is for.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I got it from the console, but because the output is so long, the startup part is cut out. Is there a file where the log is stored?

Comment: Set your log level to info, clear the eclipse console and restart. Copy past the contents of the console in an edit to your question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis How can I set it to info? I'm running my application in a Tomcat instance and have no main method.

Comment: http://blog.mubasher.net/index.php/2015/10/09/stand-alone-restfull-web-service-spring-boot/

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the contextConfig location

```
  <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
```

param-value is missing. Please give the location of the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml and try again. hope this helps

Comment: Would the location be mvc-servlet-dispatcher?

Comment: it would be your mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: Ah just seen this, will try it