# Spring 5 : Restful API without spring boot

Tags: spring

I would like to create a restful API with Spring but without springboot. I tried with WebMvcConfigurer but I'm not sure that this is the one that I should use as this will not be a MVC project (no view, only webservices)

Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29416804/657224

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating spring rest services without using spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416804/creating-spring-rest-services-without-using-spring-boot)

Comment: Hi, yes I saw this one but I wonder if this is the good choice to go with an "MVC" setup for a restful API as I suppose I will import some dependencies that I won't use or something?