# To use Autowired without spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-autoconfiguration

I am trying to use Spring Autowired and Configs without using springboot. I have the below dependencies and the class look like below (I got a service, component and config class). But I get SomeService as null always. What am I missing?

Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.somepackage")
public class AppConfig {
}
```

Component

```
 @Component
    public class TestClass extends Step {
    
        @Autowired
        private SomeService someservice;
    
        public void testConnectivity() {
            someservice.insertTransaction();
        }
    }
```

Service

```
    @Service
    public class SomeService {
    }
```

MainClass

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
   SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application .class);
   application.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);
   application.run(args);
    }
}
```

Dependency

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You say `without using springboot.` but using `spring-boot-autoconfigure` - you don't need it. Attach a code of main class pleas

Comment: added main class. okay I will remove autoconfigure. I was thinking to read from application.properties this is required.

Comment: Your main method doesn't do anything, so obviously nothing will bootstrap nor inject dependencies.

Comment: SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(MainApplication.class);
application.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);
application.run(args);

Comment: With the above it doesnt work either

Comment: Because `SpringApplication` is from `spring-boot`. If you don't want to use `spring-boot` you have to configure all needed beans manually through configurations and create context manually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [creating spring rest services without using spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416804/creating-spring-rest-services-without-using-spring-boot)